# Why can't I write code inside of document.onload instead of putting a function?

Tags: javascript

I'm able to do this:

```
document.onload = init();
```

But not this:

```
document.onload = function() {
  alert('Test');
}
```

How come?

Edit:

This is init()

```
var init = function() {
  alert('Test');
}
```

Comment: `document.onload = init();` is nothing but a call to `init` functin and assigning the returned value to `document.onload`. `document.onload = init;` <-- Remove `()`;

Comment: I think second one is doable and not the first one.

Comment: I've put an `alert()` in `init`. When I do `document.onload = init();` the alert pops up, but when I do `document.onload = init;` it doesn't. How come?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add some parenthesis around the function, then another pair of parenthesis at the end to call it:

```
document.onload = (function() {
  init();
})()
```

Comment: You don't even need `document.onload = ` in that case. Just use IIFE

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.onload = init(){ 
    alert('Test');
}
```

Overload `init` function, `document.onload` initially calls the `init` function.